# RDP into 2 computers

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

I am trying to remote into my HTPC and my Basement PC from work and home.

#### Here are the symptoms:

- HTPC>Basement PC works just fine over 3389
- Vice verse over port 3395 (which I used before) no longer works

#### Here is what I have done:

- Firewall is setup to allow the ports
- firewall on the pc is turned off
- remote settings on pc are correct.
- Regedit edit port # is 3395
- I can map the C: and D: drives from the basement computer
- I can ping both the machines from each other
- I ran `netstat -a` and it says its listening

#### Equipment

- ATT Uverse Router
- 2 unmanaged switches
- lenovo desktop
- dell desktop
- both wired at gigabit
- same subnet

#### IPCONFIG /all

```
HTPC
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.67(Pre
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, August 2
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 242020425
    DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-B

Basement
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.68(Prefer
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August 23
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, August 24,
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
```

Anything I may be looking over?

Comment: I've had similar problems when the two remote machines are on different subnets from one another.

Comment: I have added my ipconfig /all settings for both computers.

Comment: I flipped flopped the ports.  All is well now...Something must have been hosed up.  This can be closed